# images shakes when I slide them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Got a slider for online shop, for multiple images of product. Made by myself with jquery. If you lead the cursor very quickly, the images don't change, and overlap each other. How to fix it?

It will be nice if somebody has a similar plugin for gallery.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/OxQaWv

```
<div class="product__slider">
        <div class="product__slider-photo">
            <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841024/v841024287/1c91c/h8XGWuDBjn8.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="0">
            <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c639816/v639816421/38089/GjCdk2X_ifI.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="1">               
            <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837433/v837433282/4d8fe/UEbY-oQHoD4.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="2">   
        </div>
        <div class="product__slider-nav">
            <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841024/v841024287/1c91c/h8XGWuDBjn8.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="0">
            <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c639816/v639816421/38089/GjCdk2X_ifI.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="1">               
            <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837433/v837433282/4d8fe/UEbY-oQHoD4.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="2">
        </div>          
    </div>
```

CSS (LESS):

```
.product {
 &__slider {
    width: 55%; 
box-sizing: border-box;

    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 580px;

    background-color: #fff;
    &-photo {
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 600px;

        position: relative;
        img {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;


            transition: .25s;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }           
    }   
    &-nav {

        margin: 30px auto 0;
        display: flex;

        justify-content: center;
        img {               
            margin-right: 10px;
            height: 120px;
            max-width: 120px;
            object-fit: cover;
            width: auto;
            display: block;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    }           
}
```

}

JS (jQuery):

```
var currentSlide = $(".product__slider-photo img:first").attr('data-id');


$(".product__slider-photo img").hide();
$(".product__slider-photo img:first").show();



$(".product__slider-nav img").hover(function(){
    var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');       
    if (currentSlide != dataId) {           
        $(".product__slider-photo img").css('display', 'none');
        $('.product__slider-photo img[data-id="'+dataId+'"]').fadeIn(150);
        currentSlide = dataId;
        console.log(currentSlide);          
    }       
});
```

Comment: i don't see the issue in your slider

Comment: @TemaniAfif hm...try to move the mouse over the images very fast (not over one, over all (3) images).

Comment: yes i tried to do it fastly and i see nothing strange

Comment: by the way, why you want to move it fast ? maybe by doing this you are creating a strange behavior

Comment: @Alexxosipov is this what you want ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGvqKL

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes, thanks. But is this ok to change the images like that, not show/hide method? And how to make transition for opacity in that case?

Comment: @Alexxosipov if you want an animation try this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zERgMp